# How does Mac OS X Finder determine header color?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, appkit, nscolor

I am designing a table-like control using Cocoa/Objective-C. Since I want to emulate the look of Finder on Mac, I retrieve system colors when drawing my table.

In particular, use `[NSColor controlAlternatingRowBackgroundColors]` for the table rows, which looks reasonably good in my opinion. However, when it comes to the table headers, I have some issues:

`[NSColor headerTextColor]` yields a black color (which is fine for me, since Finder's header captions are black, as well), but I expected `[NSColor headerColor]` to yield a color against which the text can be read well. However, `[NSColor headerColor]` yields a pretty dark gray - obviously differing from Finder's header color.

So, is it normal for `headerColor` to be that dark? How does Finder determine its header colors (is this even documented)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table view headers in Finder haven't been a solid color since before Mac OS X 10.0. First they were "lickable" Aqua blue (or white, unselected) gradients, then they got a bit flatter over time, and since Yosemite (10.10) they've used the blurry translucent effect that's otherwise accessible to developers as [`NSVisualEffectView`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsvisualeffectview).

In any case, `headerColor` and several other `NSColor` system colors (like `gridColor`) don't reflect current UI designs. It's probably worth [filing a bug to Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com) about either deprecating the methods, mentioning in the documentation exactly which colors are still used for what, or both.

If you want headers that match Finder, and you're not using `NSTableView` (which gets them for free), `NSVisualEffectView` is probably what you want.